# Redirecting to a Directory in Apache

Tags: linux, apache

I'm stuck here, I'm using apache on ubuntu and I'm rusty with rewrite rules, I wonder if someone can help me with this.

I'm trying to redirect users to directory upon typing url

```
monitor.mydomain.com --> monitor.mydomain.com/zabbix
```

Thank you

Comment: Upvoted this and the answer because it was the only place I could find the answer after 30 minutes of Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question should be asked over at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) but here goes..

[Apache Docs: Redirecting and Remapping](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) covers remapping pretty well, an easy example using for example VirtualHost to solve your problem follows:

Put the following in your httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /path/to/zabbix
ServerName monitor.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And then restart the apache web server

```
$ apachectl restart
```